# How many strings of length 16 using (‘a’ to ‘z’) where no other letter (except 'a') may appear more than once and the letter ‘a’ has 2 conditions?

Tags: combinatorics

‘a’ must appear more than twice & 'a' should have a non-strictly ascending difference (difference meaning the number of letters separating each occurring 'a' from left to right) from each other (aaaa baca deaf ghai, the example here has ascending difference of +0,+0,+0,+1,+1,+2,+3 (from the 1st 'a' to the last 'a')

Whole question:
How many strings are there of length 16, using the letters from ‘a’ to ‘z’ where

no letter (except 'a') may appear more than once (other letters can only be used 0 or 1 times),

the letter ‘a’ must appear more than twice (‘a’ must appear 3 or more times) and

'a' should have a non-strictly ascending difference (difference meaning the number of letters
separating each occurring 'a' from left to right) from each other (aaaa baca deaf ghai, the
example here has ascending difference of +0,+0,+0,+1,+1,+2,+3 (from the 1st 'a' to the last 'a'))?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.